# How do make a metallic transition like this?

Tags: shaders

I would like to recreate this [image: Image being replicated]

And I have succeeded created the metallic effect with a B&W reference of the same packaging, leaving in white the areas I want metallic and black the areas I don't. But there's a transition within the metallic image reference, also a texture, not sure if I should add something else to my mask to make it the transition like that from bright to darkness.

Mine and how's looking so far:

[image: actual render]

[image: this is my shader so far]

Comment: Hi :). The gradient looks like a reflection. E.g. white floor, dark environment

Comment: maybe you should blur your mask a bit, also you should add a bit of bump noise

Answer (score 0):

Put a "color ramp node" inbetween the color texture and the shader node (so on the yellow line) and play around with the sliders. you will fix the problem.